# How to recover old column value from parquet file after renaming?

Tags: hive, parquet, presto

**Description**

I have a managed partitioned Hive table `table_a` with data stored in Amazon S3 in parquet format. I renamed column `col_old` to `col_new`. And, I lost all the data of `col_old` because of the way parquet file works.

**Question**

Is there any way to recover values of `col_old`? (*I still have the old parquet data files.*)

Here are few things I tried:

1. Created a new table with old files and renamed `col_new` to `col_old`.
2. Created a new table with old files and added `col_old`.

Answer (score 0):

creae table with new column and do

```
insert into new table as select * from old_table
```